# how to use shell variables in xml file

Tags: xml, shell

this is my xml file

```
`<common>
   <ALL>
      <CollectTimestamps>0</CollectTimestamps>
      <DefaultDatabaseInstance>ZEH3104</DefaultDatabaseInstance>
   </ALL>
</common>`
```

my databaseinstance value ZEH3104 is hard coded value, the value keeps changing from release to release, i want to use a variable insteadt of hard coded value, i want to use a shell variable like

```
`<DefaultDatabaseInstance>$myShellVariable</DefaultDatabaseInstance>`
```

where echo $myShellVariable gives ZEH3104

but this is not working  tag is taking $myShellVariable as value for the tag instead of ZEH3104

is there any method where i can get the result. please help.

NOTE: the tags should not be modified

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

You can't.

### Long answer

Pure XML only holds data: it doesn't interpret anything. In the scenario you are describing you have to find some way to either modify or recreate the XML for every release. The simplest approach is probably to write a script that runs a find-replace on your template, replacing the tag with the shell variable and then overwriting the active configuration XML.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can but with Spring and ActiveMQ support. The key difference here is that the shell variables are intercepted. It is OFTEN done when configuring LDAP services, messaging services and sometimes done for managing UNIX/Linux scripts.

The process is fairly simple. Assuming you have a spring environment setup: First, find a framework that supports a shell variable heavy technology. A few examples: Apache ActiveMQ, Quartz, Spring (Quartz), etc...

Identify their schema and include it in the beans tag definition. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://ww.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
   xsi:schemaLocation=http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.5.0.xsd>

   <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
   <property name="urls" value="${ldap.name.url}" />
   <property name="base" value="${ldap.name.base}" />
   ...
   </bean>
</beans>
```

What will happen is the shell variables will be intercepted, where their fields will be replaced by their matching values prior to XML parsing.

Another option is to do it manually which would be the case if you didn't have, or did not want to have a Spring environment. This method excludes any need for additional frameworks. You can easily parse an XML file like any other text file, and use J2SE to search for patterns where any value that starts with ${ and ends with }, get the value in between and store it within a Properties collection as a key. Close the instream, match the value you want to populate by storing that value as the key/value pair, and open the outstream for writing, replacing all identified patterns with the matching keys stored in your Properties collection.

Now, is this this efficient?  No, and I would advise using an alternative method. In fact, the only time you really ever want to do something like this is if your creating an ANT script, you are using Java for Linux/UNIX scripting (instead of BASH scripting), or you have a need for crossing technologies (which is often the case with LDAP). But here's your solution.